# How many graphs on the vertex set {1, ..., 12} have exactly 15 edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that to solve this I have to figure out how many total possible edges there are
However, I am unsure how to do this ? 
Once I am able to figure out the number of edges, I can choose 15 out of the total possible edges and find out the answer but I am stuck, can anyone explain to me how to figure that out?

Comment: The total number of posssible edges of a graph with $n$ vertices is $n^2$ if you allow edges from an edge to itself and $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$ otherwise.

Comment: in the case of this graph though there should be a possibility of 132 edges which is what i originally thought then I would choose 15 from the 132 possible edges to get the answer. However, the answer says there are only 66 possible edges. Why are there only half as many edges possible when there should be n(n-1) edges?

Comment: @sunnyjim2479:  in an undirected graph, an edge from A to B is the same as one from B to A, so there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ edges with different endpoints.  Then if you allow loops, you add in $n$, getting $\frac 12n(n+1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the graph in question is an undirected simple graph (a graph where edges are uniquely determined by the set of their endpoints). This is the most common type of graph studied in graph theory. There are $\binom{12}{2}=\frac{12(11)}{2}=66$ possible edges and we want exactly 15, so the answer is
$$\binom{66}{15}$$
which is incidentially also known as 
$$268367258592576$$

Comment: It's worth noting that there are far fewer non-isomorphic graphs of this type (1043774, in fact.)

Comment: @Kundor I'm sure you're right. The labeled vertex set suggested that we didn't have to compute the number of those, though, and while I bet Richard Stanley could do it on the back of an envelope in a minute or two I'd consider that a pretty hard enumeration problem.